# reserve some ids for the particular rows in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to reserve ids upto some rows.
Let I have to add stores using 3 API,om,vcomm,icube
now when I add the three stores randomly using php,it will go into second database as

```
----------------------------
id | apiname | 
-----------------------------
1-500 | icube |

501-1000 | om

1001 - 2000 | vcomm
-----------------------------------------
```

As in above database when I clicked on store of icube api it will be placed within id of 1 to 500,when I click on store of om it will be placed within id of 500-1000 and when I click on vcommm it will placed with 1001-2000,not one by one.
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
insert into tablename (id,apiname) 
values ((select max(id)+1 from tablename t where t.apiname='icube'),'icube');
```

or

```
insert into tablename (id,apiname)
values ((select max(id)+1 from tablename t where t.apiname='om'),'om');
```